# How to deal with removing/disabling a virtual layer that makes QGIS unresponsive

Tags: qgis, virtual-layer

I created a virtual layer and wrote an expression that I suspect was really heavy and returns a very large data set (I was playing around). After adding the virtual layer QGIS became unresponsive and I had to close it. Now, every time I open that project, QGIS again becomes unresponsive.

Somehow I managed to save the project just after adding the layer, just before it stalled.

Is there a way to disable evaluation of virtual layers while opening the project, so that I can delete the layer or edit the virtual layer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There may be easier ways, but here is a brute force way that I think should work:

1. Backup your project .qgz file.
2. Use a zip utility to extract the contents of the .qgs file, which is just a zipped archive.
3. The resultant .qgs file contains all the project information encoded as xml. Open it with a text editor.
4. Find the SQL definition of the virtual layer that is causing grief. You could systematically locate the right xml tags, but probably much easier to just search for bits and pieces of the SQL string defining the unfortunate virtual layer.
5. Syntactically munge it to be invalid. Munge just the defining SQL statement, not the xml. (I'm not sure if its encoded in some way with escape sequences, you'll have to see.). Save.
6. Open the project from the unzipped and modified .qgs file (not the .qgz). It should now load without stalling, but with complaints.
7. Delete the layer properly within QGIS and resave.